# Problemas css en shopify

Tags: css3

el inconveniente que tengo es que cuando lo coloco a movil estas imagenes se ruedan ya que como el producto tiene una descripcion y es mas largo no deja que la imagen que se ponga debajo y hace que este se ruede, hay alguna manera de solucionarlo?

```
{% unless section.settings.sidebar %}
  <div id="full-width-filter" class="desktop-12 tablet-6 mobile-3">
    {% for block in section.blocks %}
      {% include 'filters' %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endunless %}

{% if section.settings.sidebar %}
  {% include 'collection-sidebar' %}
{% endif %}

<div class="{% if section.settings.sidebar %}desktop-12 tablet-6{% else %}desktop-12 tablet-6{% endif %} mobile-3">
  <div id="product-loop">
    {% for product in collection.products %}
      <div class="product-index {% if section.settings.products_per_row  == 2 %}desktop-6 tablet-half {% cycle ' first', ' last' %}{% elsif section.settings.products_per_row  == 3 %}desktop-4 tablet-2 {% cycle ' first', '', ' last' %}{% elsif section.settings.products_per_row == 4 %}desktop-3 tablet-half {% cycle ' first', '', '', ' last' %}{% endif %} mobile-half" data-alpha="{{ product.title }}" data-price="{{ product.price }}">
        {% include 'product-listing' %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías explicar mejor a qué te refieres con que _las imágenes se ruedan_?

Comment: si, deberia ser 2 imagenes por row pero este me sale de 1 yo creo que es por que la imagen que esta en la izquierda de arriba su texto es mas largo y por eso no se coloca una imagen ahi y se rueda esa imagen a su derecha (cross gear shin calf red shell 7mm)